# How to insert missing dates and forward fill columns after grouping by another column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data available on a monthly basis(for different securities) which I want to convert to a daily basis by adding the missing dates and forward filling the monthly data for all the days of the month(i.e. data on 12/3/2015 = data on 12/1/2015 and so on for all securities).

My data looks like this:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'ticker': ['a','a','a','b','b'], 'dt': ['12/1/2015','1/1/2016','2/1/2016','1/1/2016','2/1/2016'], 'score': [2.8,3.8,3.8,1.9,1.7]})
```

I tried creating a multi-index using dates and ticker columns, resampling using daily frequency. However, I'm getting 'ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis' error.

```
x['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(x['dt'])
dates = x.set_index('dt').resample('D').asfreq().index
ticker = x['ticker'].unique()
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((dates, ticker), names=['dt', 'ticker'])
x.set_index(['dt', 'ticker']).reindex(idx, method='bfill').reset_index()
x.set_index(['dt', 'ticker']).reindex(idx, method='ffill').reset_index().sort_values(by='ticker')
```

Expected Result:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'ticker': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'dt': ['12/1/2015', '12/2/2015', '12/3/2015', '12/4/2015', '12/5/2015', '12/6/2015', '12/7/2015', '12/8/2015', '12/9/2015', '12/10/2015', '12/11/2015', '12/12/2015', '12/13/2015', '12/14/2015', '12/15/2015', '12/16/2015', '12/17/2015', '12/18/2015', '12/19/2015', '12/20/2015', '12/21/2015', '12/22/2015', '12/23/2015', '12/24/2015', '12/25/2015', '12/26/2015', '12/27/2015', '12/28/2015', '12/29/2015', '12/30/2015', '12/31/2015', '1/1/2016', '1/2/2016', '1/3/2016', '1/4/2016', '1/5/2016', '1/6/2016', '1/7/2016', '1/8/2016', '1/9/2016', '1/10/2016', '1/11/2016', '1/12/2016', '1/13/2016', '1/14/2016', '1/15/2016', '1/16/2016', '1/17/2016', '1/18/2016', '1/19/2016', '1/20/2016', '1/21/2016', '1/22/2016', '1/23/2016', '1/24/2016', '1/25/2016', '1/26/2016', '1/27/2016', '1/28/2016', '1/29/2016', '1/30/2016', '1/31/2016', '2/1/2016','12/1/2015', '12/2/2015', '12/3/2015', '12/4/2015', '12/5/2015', '12/6/2015', '12/7/2015', '12/8/2015', '12/9/2015', '12/10/2015', '12/11/2015', '12/12/2015', '12/13/2015', '12/14/2015', '12/15/2015', '12/16/2015', '12/17/2015', '12/18/2015', '12/19/2015', '12/20/2015', '12/21/2015', '12/22/2015', '12/23/2015', '12/24/2015', '12/25/2015', '12/26/2015', '12/27/2015', '12/28/2015', '12/29/2015', '12/30/2015', '12/31/2015', '1/1/2016', '1/2/2016', '1/3/2016', '1/4/2016', '1/5/2016', '1/6/2016', '1/7/2016', '1/8/2016', '1/9/2016', '1/10/2016', '1/11/2016', '1/12/2016', '1/13/2016', '1/14/2016', '1/15/2016', '1/16/2016', '1/17/2016', '1/18/2016', '1/19/2016', '1/20/2016', '1/21/2016', '1/22/2016', '1/23/2016', '1/24/2016', '1/25/2016', '1/26/2016', '1/27/2016', '1/28/2016', '1/29/2016', '1/30/2016', '1/31/2016', '2/1/2016'], 'score': [2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.7]})
```

Actual Result: Getting error - 'ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis'

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: please read this before posting; [ask], [mcve]. especially the part on sample data would be helpful. and please don't post pictures.

Comment: Thanks  Zanshin. I appreciate your response. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, lets try with `groupby` and `resample`:

```
x['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(x['dt'])
x = x.set_index('dt')

df_out = x.groupby('ticker', as_index=False, group_keys=False)\
          .apply(lambda d: d.resample('D').ffill())
```

Output:

```
          ticker  score
dt                      
2015-12-01      a    2.8
2015-12-02      a    2.8
2015-12-03      a    2.8
2015-12-04      a    2.8
2015-12-05      a    2.8
2015-12-06      a    2.8
2015-12-07      a    2.8
2015-12-08      a    2.8
2015-12-09      a    2.8
2015-12-10      a    2.8
2015-12-11      a    2.8
2015-12-12      a    2.8
2015-12-13      a    2.8
2015-12-14      a    2.8
2015-12-15      a    2.8
2015-12-16      a    2.8
2015-12-17      a    2.8
2015-12-18      a    2.8
2015-12-19      a    2.8
2015-12-20      a    2.8
2015-12-21      a    2.8
2015-12-22      a    2.8
2015-12-23      a    2.8
2015-12-24      a    2.8
2015-12-25      a    2.8
2015-12-26      a    2.8
2015-12-27      a    2.8
2015-12-28      a    2.8
2015-12-29      a    2.8
2015-12-30      a    2.8
...           ...    ...
2016-01-03      b    1.9
2016-01-04      b    1.9
2016-01-05      b    1.9
2016-01-06      b    1.9
2016-01-07      b    1.9
2016-01-08      b    1.9
2016-01-09      b    1.9
2016-01-10      b    1.9
2016-01-11      b    1.9
2016-01-12      b    1.9
2016-01-13      b    1.9
2016-01-14      b    1.9
2016-01-15      b    1.9
2016-01-16      b    1.9
2016-01-17      b    1.9
2016-01-18      b    1.9
2016-01-19      b    1.9
2016-01-20      b    1.9
2016-01-21      b    1.9
2016-01-22      b    1.9
2016-01-23      b    1.9
2016-01-24      b    1.9
2016-01-25      b    1.9
2016-01-26      b    1.9
2016-01-27      b    1.9
2016-01-28      b    1.9
2016-01-29      b    1.9
2016-01-30      b    1.9
2016-01-31      b    1.9
2016-02-01      b    1.7

[95 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks Scott! This solution is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Lifelong_Learner Would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) and upvoting if your rep points are good enough.  Thank you.

Comment: I tried implementing this code for the larger data but got this error:
"ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit" . Can you let me know if there is a way to handle this error. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, what I think is happening here is that for a ticker, you have two records for the same day.  The question is how do you want to aggregate those two records? Mean, max, first, or last.  d.resample('D').max().ffill()