# Pandas- How do I bfill across multiple dates/entities?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I'm trying to bfill stock data using Pandas. The issue I'm having is that my data-frame has multiple tickers (Dim_Assets.Index). At some level, I think a partition is needed. df1 below is the data-frame I have now. df2 is the desired output.

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'AssetDate': ['1/1/2020', '1/3/2020', '1/1/2020', '1/3/2020'], 'Dim_Assets.Index': [1,1,2,2],'AssetPrice': [50, 56, 100, 96]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df1['AssetDate']=pd.to_datetime(df1['AssetDate'], format='%m/%d/%Y')


d2 = {'AssetDate': ['1/1/2020', '1/2/2020', '1/3/2020', '1/1/2020', '1/2/2020', '1/3/2020'], 'Dim_Assets.Index': [1,1,1,2,2,2],'AssetPrice': [50, 50, 56, 100, 100, 96]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
df2['AssetDate']=pd.to_datetime(df2['AssetDate'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

How can I achieve the required df2?

Comment: Answer found in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54067391/how-to-insert-missing-dates-and-forward-fill-columns-after-grouping-by-another-c

Answer (score 1):

Backfilling won't add rows to your dataframe. It is an alias for `fillna`. So if you want something backfilled, you need to add rows with dates and empty values to backfill. Then you can groupby Dim_Assets.Index and backfill by group.

```
df.gropuby('Dim_Assets.Index').bfill(...)
```

Comment: What method can be used to add these rows?